# Responsive navigation bug

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav, responsive

I am using bootstrap. I need to make this responsive but i couldn't handle it. Specially search bar frustrate me.

I want menu elements collapsed under 992px. Waiting for suggestions. Thanks.

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/erenesto/pen/MbMmmg)

**Example Code:**

```css
nav.navbar-default {
  background-color: #232323;
  margin-right: 1px;
  border: 0;
}
div.navbar-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 20;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .container {
  padding: 0;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .col {
  padding: 0;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .col:first-child {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .menu-middle {
  width: 64.66667%;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .menu-right {
  width: 10.33333%;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .logo {
  background: url(/assets/img/logo.png) center no-repeat;
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 134px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .logo.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 0;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .logo:hover {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .logo span.brand-name {
  position: absolute;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav {
  height: 36px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav > li > a {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #999;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav > li > a .fa {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav .dropdown {
  background-color: #555555;
  margin-right: 2.2px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav .navbar-form {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav .nav-search-bar .form-control,
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav .nav-search-bar .btn-default {
  background-color: #555555;
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  padding: 20px 32px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav .nav-search-bar .form-control:focus,
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav .nav-search-bar .btn-default:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .top-nav .nav-search-bar .btn-default {
  padding: 9px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: 0;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .main-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  padding: 24px 0 24px 15px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .main-nav > li > a {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-right: 22px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .main-nav > li > a:hover {
  background-color: #00a9df;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .main-nav > li.active a {
  background-color: #00a9df;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .main-nav > li.active a:hover,
div.navbar-wrapper .nav-wrap .main-nav > li.active a:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .my-cart-wrap {
  background-color: #ff9c00;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 134px;
  display: table;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .my-cart-wrap .shopping-cart-wrap {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .my-cart-wrap .shopping-cart-wrap a {
  color: #fff;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .my-cart-wrap .shopping-cart-wrap a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .my-cart-wrap .shopping-cart-wrap .fa-shopping-cart {
  font-size: 18px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .my-cart-wrap .shopping-cart-wrap span.my-cart {
  font-size: 14px;
}
div.navbar-wrapper .my-cart-wrap .shopping-cart-wrap span.cart-item {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- NAVBAR -->
<div class="navbar-wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
          <div class="container navbar-wrap">
            <div class="navbar-header col col-md-3">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#"><span class="brand-name">Project name</span></a>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-md-8  menu-middle">

              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse nav-wrap">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-nav">
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>My Account</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>My Wishlist</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-external-link" aria-hidden="true"></i>Checkout</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">USD <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">TL</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><a href="#">EURO</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>

                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Turkish<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">English</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <div class="input-group nav-search-bar">
                    <form class="navbar-form">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your keyword">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                  </span>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav main-nav text-uppercase">
                  <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">Living Room</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">Bedroom</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">Dinning</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="">Contact Us</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
            <div class="my-cart-wrap col col-sm-1 menu-right">
              <div class="shopping-cart-wrap">
                <a href="#">
                  <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <br>
                  <span class="my-cart">My Cart</span>
                  <br>
                  <span class="cart-item">0 Item</span>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Example:

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar   just take the code

Comment: This is simple use code from bootstrap site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this code for searchbar.**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>
```